# Adding ARIA Attributes to Accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

Suffering from a lack of brain power and can't seem to figure out the following issue:

```
 $('#accordion .title h4').click(function(){
        if($('#accordion .title').attr('aria-selected')==='false') {
              $('#accordion .title').attr('aria-selected' , 'true');
              $('#accordion .title').attr('aria-expanded' , 'true');
              $('#accordion .accordion-content').attr('aria-hidden' , 'false');
        }
        else{
              $('#accordion .title').attr('aria-selected' , 'false'); 
              $('#accordion .title').attr('aria-expanded' , 'false');
              $('#accordion .accordion-content').attr('aria-hidden' , 'true');         
        }
        $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(400).siblings('.accordion-
            content').slideUp(400);
        return false;
});
```

Full fiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/77zqme17/

I'm attempting to toggle the WAI-ARIA attributes for this jQuery accordion, but as it's an accordion that allows multiple open panels, my click event is firing correctly if you click on the same selection twice (**Note 1**), but not if you click on a sibling and still have the original selection open (**Note 2**).

**Note 1:** Clicking on Mission twice correctly changes the ARIA attributes to aria-selected="true" aria-expanded"true" and aria-hidden="false"

**Note 2:** Clicking on Vision when Mission is still open changes the attributes correctly for Vision but toggles Mission's classes back to aria-selected="false" aria-expanded"false" and aria-hidden="true" even though it's still open.

I've attempted work some magic with it, but alas no good results, so this was my original script snippet. Any suggestions on how to get this gosh darn thing working correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With each click you should make changes local to that click. Using `this` changes the aria attributes of only the `title` and `content` of the accordion selected.

```
$('#accordion .title h4').click(function(){
  var title = $(this).closest('.accordion-container').find('.title'),
      content = $(this).closest('.accordion-container').find('.accordion-content');

  if(title.attr('aria-selected')==='false') {
    title.attr('aria-selected' , 'true');
    title.attr('aria-expanded' , 'true');
    content.attr('aria-hidden' , 'false');
  }
 else{
   title.attr('aria-selected' , 'false'); 
   title.attr('aria-expanded' , 'false');
   content.attr('aria-hidden' , 'true');         
 }
 $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(400).siblings('.accordion-content').slideUp(400);
 return false;
});
```

```js
$('#accordion .title h4').click(function() {
  var title = $(this).closest('.accordion-container').find('.title'),
    content = $(this).closest('.accordion-container').find('.accordion-content');

  if (title.attr('aria-selected') === 'false') {
    title.attr('aria-selected', 'true');
    title.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
    content.attr('aria-hidden', 'false');
  } else {
    title.attr('aria-selected', 'false');
    title.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    content.attr('aria-hidden', 'true');
  }
  $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(400).siblings('.accordion-content').slideUp(400);
  return false;
});
```

```css
.accordion-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-live="polite">

  <div class="accordion-container">
    <div class="title" id="tab0" tabindex="0" aria-controls="panel0" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" role="tab">
      <h4>Mission</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content" id="panel0" aria-labelledby="tab0" aria-hidden="true" role="tabpanel">

      <p>Test Test Test</p>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-container">
    <div class="title" id="tab1" tabindex="1" aria-controls="panel1" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" role="tab">
      <h4>Vision</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content" id="panel1" aria-labelledby="tab1" aria-hidden="true" role="tabpanel">

      <p>Test Test</p>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-container">
    <div class="title" id="tab2" tabindex="2" aria-controls="panel2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false" role="tab">
      <h4>Values</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content" id="panel2" aria-labelledby="tab2" aria-hidden="true" role="tabpanel">

      <p>
        Test
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Dan, you are amazing. Thank you so much for solving this for me, as well as giving a really clear explanation as to why this new snippet works. High fives all around!

Answer (score -1):

Your selector for #accordion .title is too general, it selects all of your titles. Using `this` inside the click event means it will only apply to the correct title.

Updated JS:

```
$('#accordion .title h4').click(function(){
  if($(this).closest('.title').attr('aria-selected')==='false') {
      $(this).closest('.title').attr('aria-selected' , 'true');
      $(this).closest('.title').attr('aria-expanded' , 'true');
      $(this).closest('.accordion-content').attr('aria-hidden' , 'false');
    }
  else{
      $(this).closest('.title').attr('aria-selected' , 'false'); 
      $(this).closest('.title').attr('aria-expanded' , 'false');
      $(this).closest('.accordion-content').attr('aria-hidden' , 'true');         
  }
  $(this).parent().next().slideToggle(400).siblings('.accordion-content').slideUp(400);
  return false;
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/77zqme17/2/

Comment: `$(this).closest('.accordion-content')` is invalid as `accordion-content` is not a parent of `h4`